# PL/SQL procedure to update the total field by adding the 3 marks

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have created a relation called **marks** which holds the following fields

```
create table marks (
    rollno numeric(5),
    Name varchar2(10),
    mark1 numeric(3),
    mark2 numeric(3),
    mark3 numeric(3),
    total numeric(3)
);
```

I inserted a few rows into the relation viz.

```
Insert into marks (rollno, Name, mark1, mark2, mark3)
    values(1, 'Caesar', 85, 90, 89);
Insert into marks (rollno, Name, mark1, mark2, mark3)
    values(2, 'Abi', 80, 87, 88);
Insert into marks(rollno, Name, mark1, mark2, mark3)
    values(3, 'Aish', 70, 89, 75);
```

Now I want to create a procedure that updates the **total** field by adding the 3 marks. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Two comments.  First, it is bad design to store a value that can be computed at run time.  It's not a matter of "if" a bug will cause it to be inaccurate, it's only a matter of "when".  As @Gordon LInoff suggests, a virtual column is a way to solve that if performance of actual run-time calculation becomes an issue.  Second, wihtout knowning the nature of what a 'mark' is in the real world, it appears that your data model is flawed.  Most likely each 'mark' should be a single row in a child table with FK back to MARKS.

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual column:

```
create table marks (
    rollno numeric(5),
    Name varchar2(10),
    mark1 numeric(3),
    mark2 numeric(3),
    mark3 numeric(3),    
    total numeric(3) generated always as (mark1 + mark2 + mark3)
);
```

Then it is part of the table and you don't need to do any work to keep it up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure find_total
as
begin
update marks set total=mark1+mark2+mark3;
dbms_output.put_line('Total updated');
end find_total;


begin
find_total;
end;
```